# Authorization error when deploying Ionic app on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-api, google-oauth

I developed a Web App using ionic which works perfectly in the browser.
Now, I tried to deploy it on Android using the basic command:

```
 ionic cordova run android --prod --releaseand
```

but when I try to log using Google I get this screen:
[image]

What could be the reason for this error if it works perfectly in the browser but not on the emulator? Can it be because it misses the port in the address?

Comment: Share some code please.